# Raspberry PI @reboot open xterm windows

Tags: raspbian, lxterminal, reboot, systemd-startup

Hello i am trying to open two shell scripts on reboot.

**Crontab**
My crontab is the following

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/Desktop/autoStart.sh
```

**autoStart.sh**
in this shell script is the following

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/pi/Desktop
sudo xterm -e ./startNodeServer.sh &
sudo xterm -e ./startPythonScanner.sh
```

**Error**
The error i get is

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the error message. `DISPLAY is not set`. Cron is not a part of your desktop environment, so it does not know where to display the `xterm`.

If you open an `xterm` normally, and ask `echo $DISPLAY`, it will tell you soemthing like

```
:0.0
```

That is the display identifier where windows would be displayed. Unfortunately, you cannot just put

```
DISLPLAY=':0.0'
```

in your script because

- there is a form of security that prevents opening windows on the display of another login (xauth)
- your X server may not be running yet when the cronjob is executed.

The solution depends on what kind of window manager you are running. If default raspian, it would probably be something like:

- auto-login pi (via `raspi-config`)
- put `@/home/pi/Desktop/autoStart.sh` in `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

Answer (score 0):

You **CAN NOT** start GUI scripts with `crontab` - just boot to the GUI and use  `.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/autostart` to start your scripts.

To run an application you simply add it on a line starting with a '@' character.

```
@lxterminal
```

Comment: Well, not completely true. If you are logged-in in the GUI, do an `xhost +` and put `* * * * *  /usr/bin/xterm -display :0.0 -e sleep 5` in your crontab, you'll see that you can start GUI stuff from crontab. But `xhost +` is of course bad practice.

Comment: @LjmDullart You are right, that the categorical "CAN NOT" is not correct. But in this special case: Can you be sure that the crontab `@reboot` is executed after the XServer has started. If not, there is no XServer that can display the xterm. And because `@reboot` is sometimes used to initialize e.g. special network drivers, I doubt that the X-Server is running when the script is performed.  Your answer is helpful (uv), but the comment might confuse the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Starting programs and scripts are controlled by **systemd** with Unit files. With it you can define the needed environment to run the program. But because we know nothing about your scripts and what they are doing I can only suggest a general template to start a script with GUI. Create a new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit node-server.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Node Server
Wants=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Desktop
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xterm -c /home/pi/Desktop/startNodeServer.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Enable and start the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable --now node-server.service
```

Check with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status node-server.service
```

Create and start just a second *python-scanner.service* for `startPythonScanner.sh` in the same way. Maybe you have to define `Wants=node-server.service` and `After=node-server.service` in its [Unit] section. If it doesn't work you have to look what additional environment settings are needed or you may elaborate your question.