# Start Google Assistant on boot

Tags: raspbian

I have set up a Raspberry Pi with Google Assistant. All working fine, but I would like Google Assistant to start in a terminal window automatically on boot.
The commands to start Google Assistant are:

```
source env/bin/activate
googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project-id xxxxxxxx --device-model-id xxxxxxxxxx
```

I would also like to know how to add an LED when Google Assistant is listening. Maybe a Python script.

Thank in advance

Comment: You need to enable autologin and then use the logged in user's desktop autostart file/mechanism.  Oddly we don't have a recent cannonical answer explaining this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+autologin+autostart But if you glance at those and search around for one or the other (`autologin`, `autostart`) instead of both you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @goldilocks: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104951/raspberry-pi-reboot-open-xterm-windows/104952#104952 is somewhat comparable and gives the answer (auto-login pi (via raspi-config); put `@/home/pi/Desktop/your_script.sh` in `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`), or do something elaborate with `systemd`.

Comment: Thank you all. I got it working now. I just need LED working now

Comment: @henrik If you have time to post the solution that worked for you it would be appreciated!

Comment: But of course. I used your solution and edited autotstart and added
@lxterminal -e /home/pi/start_assistant.sh &

Answer (score 0):

No buddy, you cannot do that with is 'googlesamples-assistant' package that you have installed in your raspberry-pi. This package doesn't come along with user interface, when google-hotword is summoned.
do one thing.

Install another package, that comes along with several amazing user-interfacing options when the google-assistant is running on your device. And there you are given a predefined option for LED to turn on, when Google Assistant is listening.

The link i'm providing here, follow the mannuals, and if you got any problem ping me up. I'm using this package, and it's amazing.

https://github.com/shivasiddharth/GassistPi